# Inconsistent wording between list and filter for some flag states

Tags: feature-request, flags, wording, flag-history

In the [flag summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current), the filter on the right uses different words for some statuses than the list:

1. "pending" in the list is "waiting for review" in the filter
2. "self-removed" in the list is "retracted" in the filter

I'm not sure which of the two to prefer; for 2., the flagging dialog does contain a "Retract flag" button, so that is probably the canonical one.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I think there is value in the term "self-removed". The term "retracted" is a bit ambiguous, as it doesn't necessarily specify who retracted the flag. It could also be retracted by a third party.